# Sorting a combination in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, combinations

I am trying to create a fixture list for a season based on the ids of teams. There are 20 teams, and each week, any one team can only play once. So, for week one, the fixtures would be (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), ..., (19, 20). Then week two, (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), ..., (18, 20).

Is there some sort of a formula I could do that would work the fixtures out easily? Maybe combinations are not the best thing to use here. What would be the best way about going to solve this problem?

```
class FixtutreGenerator
   a = Array(1..20)
   i = 0

  while i < a.combination(2).to_a.length
    print a.combination(2).to_a[i]
    i = i + 20
 end
end
```

Comment: There should be a way to list up all the possibilities, but have you considered how many there are? For 20 teams, the number will be `(20!)/(10! * 2^10) = 654729075`. Are you sure you want a list such long? Do you think your computer is capable of calculating that?

Comment: I hope you realize you're recomputing all combinations *each* time through the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do the scheduling of teams in a round-robin tournament. Wikipedia describes an algorithm you could use - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm.

The following implements the algorithm to print each week's pairings:

```
teams = Array(1..20)
fixed_team = teams.shift   #The fixed competitor described in the algorithm
teams.length.times do |i|

    #Create the two groups listed in the algorithm
    teams = teams.rotate
    week_teams = teams.dup.unshift(fixed_team) 
    first_group, second_group = week_teams.each_slice(week_teams.length/2).to_a
    second_group.reverse!
    weeks_pairings = first_group.zip(second_group)

    #Output the week's pairings
    puts "Week #{i + 1}: #{weeks_pairings}"
end 

#Output:
#=> Week 1: [[1, 2], [3, 20], [4, 19], [5, 18], [6, 17], [7, 16], [8, 15], [9, 14], [10, 13], [11, 12]]
#=> Week 2: [[1, 3], [4, 2], [5, 20], [6, 19], [7, 18], [8, 17], [9, 16], [10, 15], [11, 14], [12, 13]]
#=> etc
```